# NSArray may not respond to componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
NSArray *Lines = [StringData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSArray *ThisLine in Lines){

    NSArray *Items = [ThisLine componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    ...
}
```

I get a warning NSArray may not respond to componentsSeparatedByString.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that camelCase is the preferred best practice for variable names in Objective-C. As you can see SO thinks that your variables are classes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  So if I change Lines to allLines, ThisLine to thisLine and Items to itemsOfThisLine would that adhere to camelCase?  Questions 2:  This is unrelated to the warning message I get correct?

Comment: That is correct and yes it was unrelated. And you could simply make Items items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring `ThisLine` as an array when it should be an `NSString`. This should fix it

```
for (NSString *ThisLine in Lines){
```